# static seeded random.seed() returns mixed results from loaded JS, but expected results in console, and from Postman

Tags: javascript, python, django, random

I am running a server on Django, one function takes a seed through a URL param GET request, generates some data based on that seed, and sends it back.
**The URL format:**
`mysite.com/api/generate/<seed>`

**expected result:**
submitting a GET on `mysite.com/api/generate/99` gets picked up in Django as a seed value of 99. data returned is chosen with `random.choice()` seeding with `random.seed(99)` from a database which contains a single column of names. data returned is the following:

```
Walker Lewis
Dalia Aguilar
Meghan Ford
Theresa Hughes
Kenna Coffey
Kendra Ho
```

### problem

Here's where I'm getting confused (code below for each):

- 1000 requests in postman, all 1000 return perfectly equal
- approx 100 requests from the google chrome console, all are equal
- from the `generate.js` that the server sends with `index.html`, making the same call, results degenerate (examples below)

**Postman call**
very simple, `GET mysite.com/api/generate/99`

**jquery from chrome console**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/generate/99",
    success: function( result ) {
        console.log(result.data)
    }})
```

**jquery from generate.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/generate/99",
        success: function( result ) {
            var data = result.data;
        // data is now passed about the script, but debugging at the line above shows that data has already started to vary on a request by request basis
```

Both Postman and Chrome Console will return the expected results:

```
Walker Lewis
Dalia Aguilar
Meghan Ford
Theresa Hughes
Kenna Coffey
Kendra Ho
```

**generate.js:**

- The first two names are always correct
- The third is correct the majority of the time
- fouth, 20% at best (estimate)
- Anything past the forth might as well not be seeded, it just seems to be chosen at random from the database

**other information**

- I have confirmed that each request from each source is being sent and received from the server, and not from a cache
- Confirmed that all sources are hitting the same server, in the same state, and the same database

If anyone has any advice on this it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out this was due to me sending multiple AJAX requests "at once". When Django was behind Gunicorn/nginx each request gets a worker and is processed correctly. when requesting directly to docker the front end is returned with the strange data.